# Php send mail script not sending mail when hosted

Tags: php, html

When I try to send mail using the PHP

```html
<form action="tester.php" method="post">
 FullName<input type="text" name='name'><br>
    Email<input type="email" id="email-input" name='email-try'>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <br/>
    
</form>
```

```html
<?php
$to = $_POST['email-try'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$subject = "My Email Trial";
$txt = "Hey my name is ".$name." and I'm trying to see if this will work";
$headers = "From: supporter@gmail.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

header("location: type.html");
echo "Email Sent";
?>
```

script, it redirects well and shows me that it is sent but when i check my mail, i don't see it. I already hosted the site and checked the codes online but they don't work. Please what am I doing wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on one of my website. Later i fugured out that my host doesnt give me permission to use send mail. I tried sending emails by using smtp. Try using Mail.php. Here is the tutorial link.
https://www.lifewire.com/send-email-from-php-script-using-smtp-authentication-and-ssl-1171197

I am sure it will work.